# JQuery + HttpHandler returning whole html page instead of the expected data

Tags: jquery

I have a design of JQuery calling a .ashx file returning a small table, which was working fine all this time. However, suddenly the http handler seems to be returning the whole html page instead, not everytime though.

Not sure why this is happening! Any clues?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I bet the content of the result page is an error page... can you dump the result ? did you tried to open the ashx file and its argument direclty within the browser ?

Comment: Thanks. I tried to open the ashx and it seems to work fine. The handler has a try catch block to catch any error, so the .ashx should return a custom error message. There seems to be no ULS logs also showing any errors. And the most important part is that this doesnt happen all the time. It works intermittently :(

Comment: good luck to find the answer

Comment: As Steve said, get your hands on the "extra" html returned by the handler. Use a tool like Fiddler to monitor what is returned by the handler

Answer (score 1):

If the target ashx throws an exception, you be redirected to `error.aspx` page. Its content type is text/html, not the expected content.

According the comments, I suggest you to review you ashx to find the actual exception, maybe wrapping the `Process` method of you handler with a try/catch where you can log any unexpeced exception.